# How to remove external hyperlinks of generated pdf by Mpdf?

Tags: mpdf

Is there any out of the box feature to remove all external hyperlinks of generated pdf by Mpdf?

I'd like also to be able to keep all internal links (to sections).

Answer (score 0):

Remove unwanted links from your source HTML. There is no easy way to remove hyperlinks once the PDF is generated.